# Delete object property using template strings

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am trying to delete an object property with no success, using template Strings by the following ways:

1. delete object[`${property}`];
2. delete object`.${property}`;

Could you help me, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add your object data and the expected results you want.

Comment: you should be able to just use object[property] - if it's not working then something else is wrong

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want to use template literal while you can use simply like?

```
delete object[property]
```

While:

```
delete object[`${property}`]
```

is unnecessarily extra code to the preceding example code.

If you want to delete the property with some combined name, then you could use it like:

```
delete object[`custom${property}`]
```

For example:

```
const object = {
  foo: 'my foo property',
  customfoo: 'my custom foo property'
}
const prop = 'foo'
delete object['foo'] // deletes object.foo
delete object[prop] // deletes object.foo
delete object[foo] // foo is undefined, throws an error
delete object[`custom${prop}`] // deletes object.customfoo
```

Answer (score 0):

with a sample eg as we don't know your use case of using template literals here :

```js
let obj = {
    price : 10,
  name : 'random',
  qty : 15
}

const delName  = 'name';

delete obj[`${delName}`];
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can delete a property from your object with the use of template string

delete object[`${"property"}`]